# How to read text file and group values that share the same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to read this file num.txt file and group them together whether they share the same key using a dictionary like d {}, not using defaultdict

I need the output a:
{'0': {'5','1','6','2'}, '4': {'3'}, '9': {'12','11','10'}, '6': {'4'}, '5': {'4','3'}, '11': {'12'}, '7':{'8'}}

```
0 5
4 3
0 1
9 12
6 4
5 4
0 2
11 12
9 10
0 6
7 8
9 11
5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('num.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split()
        if key in d:
            d[key].append(value)
        else:
            d[key] = [value]

print(d)

# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'0': ['5', '1', '2', '6'], 
#                              '4': ['3'],
#                              '9': ['12', '10', '11'], 
#                              '6': ['4'], 
#                              '5': ['4', '3'],
#.                             '11': ['12'],
#                              '7': ['8']})
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using defaultdict? like just using d{}

Comment: `defaultdict` on average performs better than dict's when performing these tasks you can just turn `d` back to a dict using `dict(d)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` and `defaultdict` module as well.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

d = defaultdict(set)
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for k, v in r: d[k].add(v)
d = dict(d)
#{'0': {'5','1','6','2'}, '4': {'3'}, '9': {'12','11','10'}, '6': {'4'}, '5': {'4','3'}, '11': {'12'}, '7':{'8'}}
```